# Subviews not as large in the simulation

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, autolayout

I've created several subviews as seen here:

[image]

However, when I try to run the program the subviews only take up four fifths of the screen. Any idea why this is happening?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add constraints. (leading and trailing)

**Select the view**
[image]
**Tap add new constraints**
[image]
**Add new constraints for leading trailing top and height**
[image]
**You should be able to see the new constraints if you select the view**
[image]

I strongly advise a constraints tutorial.
Also it seems that you will need to scroll this so maybe a something that scrolls will help you to display subviews for this situation:
 - ScrollView
 - TableView
 - CollectionView

Comment: If i set fixed height then how could all 5 subview display in small devices?

Comment: If your content has the possibility of being larger than the screen size you would need to use a scrollView, or if your content supports it use a UITableView or UICollectionView. 99% of the views I create now are created from UICollectionViews

Comment: Use a scroll view for this but it is a bit more tricky too setup the constraints in subviews of a scroll view.

If you do not wish to have a scroll view, you need to play around with compression resistance and priority or make the views proportional to the superview. (there are other ways to achieve this as well)

Answer (score 0):

You need to first contraint your views such that they have the desired width and height that you require. After that select the views (if they cannot be visible all at one ) and goto editor > embed in > scroll view.

Now all your views will reside inside the scroll view. but in order to scroll properly, you need to constraint your scroll view as well to ensure that the scroll view is within the view bound.

Add the desired vertical spacing between the subviews. 
Or 
Add all your sub views into a stack view that would align your items vertically.

for more info look up [UIScrollView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview) and [Layout Using Stack Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/LayoutUsingStackViews.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have limited number of `UIVIew` and want to display all in single Screen without `UIScrollView` then you just need to add `UIView` constraint like below

**Note:** No fix height of any `UIView` so it will resize or increase as per device screen.

**1.** First `UIView` constraint to `Top` `Leading` `Trailing` `Bottom`.

**2.** Second `UIView` constraint to `Top` `Center Horizontal First View` `Equal Width of First View` `Equal Height of First View`

**3.** Third `UIView` constraint to `Top` `Center Horizontal of Second View` `Equal Width Second View` `Equal Height of Second View`

**4.** Forth `UIView` constraint to `Top` `Center Horizontal of Third View` `Equal Width Third View` `Equal Height of Third View`

**5.** Fifth `UIView` constraint to `Top` `Center Horizontal of Forth View` `Equal Width Forth View` `Equal Height of Forth View` `Bottom`

so it will looks like below.

**1. In StoryBoard**

[image]

**2. Device or Simulator Look**

[image]

**Note:** **If you have large number of `UIView` then the most preferred way is to add inside `UIScrollView`**

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the `Storyboard` , the views that you have placed, you just *drag and dropped* them from `Library` and maybe resized it using the *corner edges* of the that particular `View` .

Now the reason why this is happening

> You are using storyboard design of iPhone SE (you can see that at
>   bottom) and you are launching it on simulator of iPhone 8

Now, if you run the same on `iPhone SE's` simulator , it will display perfectly !

**But if you want it to appear same on all devices , then you need to use `Auto Layout constraints`**

You can find a lot of awesome `Auto Layout` tutorials on the internet which will teach you a lot of things and it is really essential for you to learn `Auto Layout` if you want to proceed further in ***iOS development***

I have attached a link below for one of the tutorial that I used :

[Auto Layout Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/443-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-11-getting-started)